# output format for strace in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, strace

Does anybody know the output format for `strace` in cygwin? It seems to me, through experimentation with options, that the first two columns are microseconds since process start time, in some way, but I can't find any explanation as to what they are or how they should be used. What I think they are is that the first number is the usec to complete the system call and the second is usec since process start. Does anybody know for certain?

```
excerpt from strace -f ls
   35   33002 [main] ls 2364 void: 0x0 = signal (3, 0x1)
   38   33040 [main] ls 2364 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: line 1180:  /dev/pty1<0x180335700> usecount + -1 = 1
   38   33078 [main] ls 2364 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: not closing archetype
   41   33119 [main] ls 2364 init_cygheap::close_ctty: closing cygheap->ctty 0x180335700
   39   33158 [main] ls 2364 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: closing passed in archetype 0x0, usecount 0
   38   33196 [main] ls 2364 fhandler_pty_slave::cleanup: /dev/pty1 closed, usecount 0
   39   33235 [main] ls 2364 fhandler_pty_slave::close: closing last open /dev/pty1 handle
  121   33356 [main] ls 2364 fhandler_console::free_console: freed console, res 1
```

Answer (score 0):

first = time between two strace outputs
second = cumulative time from program start

```
   35   33002 [main] ls 2364 void: 0x0 = signal (3, 0x1)
     38+33002=33040
   38   33040 [main] ls 2364 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: line 1180:  
     38+33040=33078
   38   33078 [main] ls 2364 fhandler_base::close_with_arch: not closing archetype
     41+33079=33119
   41   33119 [main] ls 2364 init_cygheap::close_ctty: closing cygheap->ctty 0x180335700
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.